# R ifelse statement for creating new column based on observations found in others

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to write an ifelse statement that looks at the observations of variable3 and variable4 and returns the values for a new variable5. If the value of variable4 is greater than the value of variable 3, I want the value of variable5 to be (variable4 / variable3) %*% -1. If the value of variable4 is less than the value of variable 3, I want variable 5 to be (variable3 / variable4). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: data frame]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: What do you think `%*%` is doing? Here, it will complain about non-conformal arguments, since it's just a vector. Do you mean `%%`, the modulus operator? Have you tried anything with `ifelse`? Are you sure you _need_ `ifelse`? If it is just the modulus you need, then `%% 1` on values between 0 and 1 is a no-op, so perhaps just `variable5 = (variable4 / variable3) %% 1`. (Though I'm assuming non-negative values.)

Answer (score 0):

Ifelse looks like this: condition, valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse, so:

```
variable5 = ifelse(variable4 > variable3, (variable4 / variable3) %% 1, variable3 / variable4)
```

Comment: Presumably these are columns inside a data frame, say `df1`, so you'd want to prefix each variable name with `df1$` to make it operate on those. e.g. `df1$variable5 = ifelse...`

Comment: or use `base::transform` or `dplyr::mutate` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized way.

```r
variable3 <- c(111, 278, 79, 222)
variable4 <- c(179, 201, 55, 178)
df1 <- data.frame(variable3, variable4)

df1$variable5 <- with(df1, pmax(variable3, variable4)/pmin(variable3, variable4))
df1$variable5 <- df1$variable5 * (2*(df1$variable3 > df1$variable4) - 1)

df1
#>   variable3 variable4 variable5
#> 1       111       179 -1.612613
#> 2       278       201  1.383085
#> 3        79        55  1.436364
#> 4       222       178  1.247191
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>